# How to define a method in class that inherits from Abstract Base Class

Tags: python

I have two abstract Classes with two methods: `getArea(width, height)` and `getPerimeter(width, height)`. Those methods are abstract too, so they can be (or not) implemented in a derived class (In my case they must be implemented).  In C# I could write `IRectangle.getArea(){}` or `IParallelogram.getPerimeter(){}` and simply make implementation. How can I do this in Python? I think that I have to use something like `super(IRectangle, self).getArea()` but I am not sure how.

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class IRectangle(ABC):
  @abstractmethod
  def getArea(width, height):
    pass
  @abstractmethod
  def getPerimeter(width, height):
    pass

class IParallelogram(ABC):
  @abstractmethod
  def getArea(parHeight, parBase):
      pass
  @abstractmethod
  def getPerimeter(parHeight, parBase):
    pass

class Calculate (IParallelogram, IRectangle):
```

Comment: So what part are you asking about?

Comment: `def getArea(width, height): <insert implementation here>`?

Comment: Is the fact that you have multiple abstract parent classes relevant to the question? I'm really not sure what you're asking about.

Comment: There should be a *third* abstract class that provides `getArea` and `getPerimeter` that both `IRectangle` and `IParallelgram` inherit from. `Calculate` also doesn't sound like something that should be a class.

Comment: These classes make no sense in the first place, in many ways. Neither `IRectangle` nor `IParallelogram` seems to actually represent a rectangle or parallelogram. None of the methods have `self` arguments. What the heck is a `Calculate`? You cannot compute the perimeter of a parallelogram given height and base.

Comment: in Calculate I want to implement methods IRectangle.getArea(), IRectangle.getPerimeter() and also  Parallelogram.getArea(), IParallelogram.getPerimeter()

Answer (score 0):

You would just make a class that inherits from the abstract class and overrides the abstract methods like you would write a regular method.

```
class A(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def f(self):
        pass

class B(A):
    def f(self):
        print ('hello')
```

If you want to override it but make it do nothing:

```
class B(A):
    def f(self):
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Your class hierarchy is upside down. First, you would define a more generic class like `Shape` as the (abstract) root of the hierarchy.

```
class Shape(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def getArea(self):
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def getPerimeter(self):
        pass
```

Then, the concrete classes `IRectangle` and `IParallelogram` would implement `getArea` and `getPerimeter` appropriately.

```
class IRectangle(Shape):
    def getArea(self):
        ...

    def getPerimeter(self):
        ...

class IParallelogram:
    def getArea(self):
        ...

    def getPerimeter(self):
        ...
```